# How to listen to changes made in clipboard in flutter desktop

Tags: linux, flutter, clipboard, desktop-application

I'm trying to recognize the changes made in the desktop clipboard. But couldn't find any package that could provide `addListener()` method to listen to the clipboard changes. Using `clipboard` from services I'm able to fetch the clipboard data. Is there a way to listen to the clipboard for real-time changes?